# React Native non-native library

Tags: react-native, mobile, frontend

I want to create a library in react-native that doesn't need any linking and any native code, namely, it is just a pure-javascript component.

Nowadays, I only found the [react-native-create-library](https://github.com/frostney/react-native-create-library) but it is oriented for native modules. I can create my library with this one but wouldn't be very "lean".

Do you know some library/article to create an full-javascript library for react-native ?

Thank you very much!

Comment: have you tried react-native-create-library-full alternative react-native-create-bridge. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-create-library-full. https://github.com/peggyrayzis/react-native-create-bridge

Comment: I don't really understand. If it only uses JS, why not create a plain JS library? Why does it have to be part of React Native?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the steps:

- run `npm init` in cmd
- give answers to all questions.
- create components here
- create `index.js` file and import your component in that
- export you module in `index.js` file
- login in npm by using `npm login` command
- List item `npm publish` to publish it on npm.

here is the library which I created for TextInput https://github.com/shashinbhayani/rn-textfield/tree/master/src

you can check there how I created the library.